# How to search the internet for strings that consist mostly of math notation?

Tags: online-resources

Is there a trick to search the internet for math notation?  For example what if I want to search the internet for "X / ~" ?  The default google search is useless for this and for similar searches where most of the search characters are not letters or numbers.  Google code search allows this kind of search within source code, but this service will shut down in a few months and anyway it searches only source code not math.

Comment: There's [(uni)quation](http://uniquation.com/en/), and there's [$\LaTeX$ Search](http://latexsearch.com/).

Comment: By the way, since this probably came up in relation to my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74590/what-is-the-math-notation-for-this-type-of-function/74594#74594), I was using the notation in the context of an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) and, in particular, it refers to the set of equivalence classes, a.k.a. [the quotient set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Quotient_set)

Comment: I've retagged the question, since I believe that the tag [tag:searching] was intended for questions about various search algorithms. If my impression is wrong, feel free to retag the question again. (If this is the case, it might be nice to correct the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/searching/info), too.)

Comment: I found [this](http://saskatoon.cs.rit.edu/tangent/?query=x^{2}%2By^{2}) and [this](http://saskatoon.cs.rit.edu/min/) (But I am unable to search for the query in the latter, although according to description [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~dprl/Software.html) is should be a search interface.

Comment: Above Latex search is useless, too.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician uniquation seems to be gone - or at least this domain no longer works. I have asked whether somebody know more about this: [Where did uniquation go?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4114469)

Answer (score 8):

See my side-project, it is developing its indices currently.

http://approach0.xyz

I will publish its first release when the entire math StackExchange is indexed.

Also, I am hoping someone interested can join and form a community to push this project forward, this is the reason I am posting here, even if this project is not fully ready for public using.

EDIT:

If you are interested in this project or have any amazing idea to help it improve, please follow this twitter account: https://twitter.com/approach0
, mention #approach0 to send feedbacks/questions. Approach0 will post updates on twitter too.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using [symbolhound.com](http://www.symbolhound.com). I recently found this site, it will do a search for specific symbols, and is good for programming. May be good for math, just searched '4x^2' and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can search for mathematical formulas and symbols using [searchOnMath](http://www.searchonmath.com/).

Answer (score 2):

A few years ago we developed the search engine [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/), in order to search for mathematical formulas. Recently our tool has indexed both: Mathematics and MathOverflow.

Currently, SearchOnMath is the mathematical search engine with the largest number of indexed sites (including Wikipedia, Wolfram MathWorld, among others ...).

EDIT:

We released on September 2021 a Beta version for arXiv, available at [searchonmath.com/arxiv](https://www.searchonmath.com/arxiv).

Since March 2022 some results may be available only for subscribers. If you like SearchOnMath, please consider subscribing. This will help us on paying for our servers.

Comment: Great idea. I tried searching for `:=` but there's no results (see [here](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%3A%3D#t=1651078826841))

Comment: Hi @stevec, when searching for mathematical formulas (or symbols), you must use the \\( and \\) delimiters. You can see visiting [here](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%5C%28%20%3A%3D%20%5C%29%20).

You can check a more complex example [here](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=Shannon%27s%20entropy,%20%5C%28H%28X%29%20%3D%20-%5Csum_%7Bx%20%5Cin%20%5Cmathbf%7BX%7D%7D%20p%28x%29%20%5Clog%20p%28x%29%5C%29,%20measures%20how%20informative%20the%20mass%20function%20%5C%28p%5C%29%20is%20about%20the%20occurrence%20of%20the%20possible%20values%20of%20variable%20%5C%28X%5C%29.).